# Cannot acces object properties. Returns undefined (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, meteor

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude from a object. Why is it returning *Undefined*?. I am using .find() beacuse of this: https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/

> ```
> var LatLngs = Shops.find({_id:template.data._id}, {fields: {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}, limit:1}).fetch();
>
> console.log(LatLngs);
> ```
>
> Console:
>
> ```
> [Object]
> 0: Object_id: "vNHYrJxDXZm9b2osK"
> latitude: "xx.x50785"
> longitude: "x.xx4702"
> __proto__: 
> Objectlength: 1
> __proto__: Array[0]
> ```

try 2:

> ```
> var LatLngs = Shops.find({_id:template.data._id}, {fields: {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}, limit:1}).fetch();
>
> console.log(LatLngs.longitude);
> ```
>
> Console:
>
> ```
> undefined
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` method of Mongo cursors returns an array, so you have to access the longitude of the first item in the array : `LatLngs[0].longitude`.

Moreover, you're working on the client, thus using MiniMongo, a browser reimplementation of the Mongo query language : you can't make the same assumptions on how `findOne` will perform versus `find` because it's not the same implementation as regular server-side MongoDB engine.

Just use `findOne`, it has been specifically designed for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

[fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) returns an array. In your first example you'd need to do something like this:

```
// fetch an array of shops
var shops = Shops.find(...).fetch();
// get the first shop
var shop = shops[0];
// if the shop actually exsists
if (shop) {
  // do something with one of its properies
  console.log(shop.latitude);
}
```

The linked article doesn't apply in this case - you are not testing if it exists, you are actually fetching it and reading its contents.

Use [findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) instead:

```
// get a matching shop
var shop = Shops.findOne(...);
// if the shop actually exsists
if (shop) {
  // do something with one of its properies
  console.log(shop.latitude);
}
```